# How do you use "knack" in a sentence?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

On this post [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/word-for-inability-to-think-in-certain-ways/139578#139578), it says:

> Another word which comes to my mind is "Knack". It can be used to show
>   how someone has a specific talent. Again as an example - Tim is good
>   with musical instruments, and yet he doesn't have **the knack to** come up
>   with original tunes like his brother has.

I'm an American, so I use the Merriam-Webster dictionary. It's just convenient.

> 1 a : a clever trick or stratagem  b : a clever way of doing something
>   2 : a special ready capacity that is hard to analyze or teach 3
>   archaic   : an ingenious device;  broadly   : TOY, KNICKKNACK synonyms
>   see GIFT

I use the term myself with the *for* preposition or the *of* preposition, even though I think the *for* preposition may be more common.

> Little Lucy has **a knack for** getting into trouble, but she's so cute and friendly that most people never notice.

I wish to know the distinctions among *a knack for*, *a knack to*, and *a knack of*.

Comment: I've never encountered it with anything but *for*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I can't really believe you're not familiar with people having [*the knack **of**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+knack+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doing something*. According to Google Books that's about 20 times more common than having [*the knack **for**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+knack+for%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doing it*. Mind you, I never heard of anyone having [*the knack **to**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+knack+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) do it*. Most of those hits look like accidental collocations.

Comment: I have never heard 'knack to', and seldom 'knack for' but frequently 'knack of'. I would certainly not use it for writing tunes. That is a talent, not a knack! I would be more inclined to speak of the ability one develops of making a particular key turn in a difficult lock, as a knack. 'Let me do it, I've acquired the knack'. In Britain it is also used sarcastically 'He's got the knack of upsetting everyone he works with'.

Comment: @Anonymous: fwiw, I tend to say *"He's got **a** knack **for** it"*, but *"He's got **the** knack **of** it"*. For me, the former often implies ***innate ability***, whereas the latter is more likely to mean ***acquired aptitude***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers AmE/BrE divide? [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knack+of%2Cknack+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknack%20for%3B%2Cc0) G-Ngram suggests *for* took off about when I entered college and passed *of* about when I left academe. I think, too, my own disciplines tend to use *knack* as "innate talent" (he **has** the knack) which works better with *for* than does what I'm seeing in the *of* uses: "acquired skill" (he **got** the knack).

Comment: @StoneyB: That's *very* interesting! I have a pet theory that the "hip" idiomatic usages we acquire during our college years are more robustly (and unconsciously) retained in later life. Your experience seems to fit that hypothesis. There seems to be no doubt the recent upsurge in *knack **for*** is primarily US-led (I'd guess because younger speakers are keen to see a parallel with ***talent for***).

Comment: I'd have suggested *knick-knack*, but then I thought it really had nothing to do with the topic.

Comment: [*Serendipitously*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54866/2637) (*spookily*, one might say), my movie treat tonight was [The Browning Version {1951 original}](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043362/), where "The Crock" starts his brilliant "speech" with *"I did not possess **the knack of** making myself liked..."*. No-one who loves learning could fail to be moved by Andrew Crocker-Harris/Michael Redgrave for the next couple of minutes. Great movie (but potentially unnerving coincidence! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really interesting!

In British English, *knack of* appears to be the more common use according to [**this**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knack+of%2Cknack+for%2Cknack+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknack%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknack%20to%3B%2Cc0) Google N-Gram. *Knack for* is used almost exactly half as much currently, but it has only come into use recently --- previously, *knack of* very clearly dominated the field. However, both expressions combined have fallen in popularity since 1950.

In American English, according to [**this**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knack%20of,knack%20for,knack%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,knack%20of;,c0;.t1;,knack%20for;,c0;.t1;,knack%20to;,c0) N-Gram, *knack for* appears to have been the preferred form since about 1980, and has been surging in popularity ever since, whereas *knack of* has retreated further into unpopularity, even though it used to be dominant in American English, like in British English.

In both American and British English, the expression *knack to* has been highly uncommon since the late 1700s and is likely considered a usage error today. It enjoyed a brief period of popularity in the late 1600s.

I strongly suggest you view the N-Grams I linked to above; they really are very illustrative and informative.

Comment: But if you extend the Ngram backwards, it looks like *"knack to"* was used in Elizabethan English; *A Knack to Know a Knave* is a play from 1594.

Comment: That's true: analysis shows that *knack to* was at its peak use in the late 1600s, when it was as popular or perhaps even more popular than *knack of*. However, *knack to* appears to have fallen out of favor since the mid-1700s.

Comment: @Peter: Let's not forget that we're talking about significantly different usages here, not just some optional choice of preposition. I've already commented on one (possibly, idiosyncratic and/or over-subtle) distinction, but there's no doubt that *"There [is a knack **to** it*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+a+knack+to+it%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) has always been idiomatically standard. No-one *ever* uses ***for*** or ***of*** in that construction.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the difference is simply this:

1) to have **a** knack **for** something (when you use 'a' you use 'for')
*He has a knack for saying the right thing at the right time.*

2) to have **the** knack **of** something (when you use 'the' you use 'of')
*He has the knack of saying the right thing at the right time.*

3) *There is a knack to this.* (speaking about the activity not the person)