# Looking for an idiom similar to sink or swim

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for an idiom - if one exists - similar to "sink or swim", but describes when someone must learn quickly (say a new job) because they are being faced with the actual experience

Answer (score 4):

I'd say [*thrown in at the deep end*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20a%20knack%20to%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22thrown%20in%20at%20the%20deep%20end%22&tbm=bks) is about as "similar" to *sink or swim* as it's possible to get.

Google Books says there are over 30,000 hits in that link - and without actually looking, I'm prepared to bet most of them are for OP's figurative sense, not the literal one.

Comment: And FF promptly comes up with the better one than my five.  Hrmph!  :-)

Comment: @jbeldock: I just have [the knack of it!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148170/how-do-you-use-knack-in-a-sentence#comment305819_148170) (More accurately, in my own favoured idiolect, *I'm just a [jammy bastard!*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jammy+bastard%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) :)

Comment: Note to self:  develop an idiodialect.  Extra points for convincing spouse it is not an idiotdialect....  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few:

1. she has to succeed or fail on her own merits
2. the training wheels are off
3. he's in the major leagues now
4. there's no safety net
5. he's on his own now

Answer (score 0):

"fish or cut bait" ... do the job or abandon it

Comment: Word/phrase requests should be backed up with reputable references. Please add at least one to your answer.